# Python Implementation of Temporal Difference Learning Not Approaching Optimum

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to create an implementation of temporal difference learning in Python based on [this](http://www45.essec.edu/professorsCV/showDeclFileRes.do?declId=11396&key=Publication-Content) paper (warning: link downloads a PDF). Try as I might though, I can't seem to get it to converge to an optimal policy. I'm wondering if my implementation is calculating something incorrectly, because I'm not much of a coder. Here's my code:

```
class QLearn:
    # Initialize the agent. Actions is a list of allowable prices.
    def __init__(self, actions=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], state=15, action=1, discount=0.999, lamb=0.9):
        self.actions = actions
        self.state = state
        self.action = action
        self.discount = discount
        self.lamb = lamb
        self.visits = {}
        self.history = {}

    # Gets the reward realized at a given state and action, along with the new state
    def getNextState(self, sold):
        newstate = self.state - sold
        if newstate < 0:
            newstate = 0
        return newstate

    # Multiply sold and price to get revenue reward
    def getReward(self, sold):
        if sold > self.state:
            reward = self.state * self.action
        else:
            reward = self.action * sold
        return reward

    # Gets the q value for a given state for the given k and t
    def getQ(self, k, t, state, action):
        return self.q[(k, t)].get((state, action), 0.0)

    # Gets the eligibility trace for a given state for the given k and t
    def getET(self, k, t, state,action):
        return self.et[(k, t)].get((state, action), 0.0)

    # Choose which action to take in the next time period
    def chooseAction(self, k, t):
        # Decide if to explore or exploit
        if random.random() < (1/float(k)):
            # Exploring, so a random action is chosen
            newaction = random.choice(self.actions)
            explore = True
            self.history[t] = (self.state, self.action)
        else:
            # Get a list of Q values for every action
            q = [self.getQ(k, t+1, self.nextState, action) for action in self.actions]
            maxQ = max(q)
            count = q.count(maxQ)
            # If there are two Q values that are the same, choose a random one
            if count > 1:
                best = [i for i in range(len(self.actions)) if q[i] == maxQ]
                i = random.choice(best)
                explore = False
            else:
                i = q.index(maxQ)
                explore = False
            newaction = self.actions[i]
            # Record decision for k and t in history
            self.history[t] = (self.state, self.action)
        return newaction, explore

    # Calculate the temporal difference error
    def TDError(self, k, t):
        if t == 10:
            delta = self.reward + self.discount * 0 - self.getQ(k, t, self.state, self.action)
        else:
            delta = self.reward + self.discount * self.getQ(k, t+1, self.nextState,
                        self.nextAction) - self.getQ(k, t, self.state, self.action)
        return delta

    # Update the eligibility trace for the current state
    def updateCurrentET(self, k, t, state, action):
        self.et[(k, t)][(state, action)] = 1

    # Update the Q values for the next episode for all state-action pairs used during this episode
    def updateQs(self, k, t):
        for i in range(t, 0, -1):
            self.q[(k+1, t)][self.history[i]] = self.q[(k, i)].get(self.history[i], 0) + \
                (1 / float(1 + self.visits.get(self.history[i], 0))) * self.tdError * \
                self.et[t].get(self.history[i], 0)

    # Update the eligibility traces for all state-action pairs used in the episode
    def updateETs(self, k, t):
        # Set all to zero if exploration
        if self.explore:
            for i in range(t, 0, -1):
                self.et[t+1][self.history[i]] = 0
        else:
            for i in range(t-1, 0, -1):
                self.et[t+1][self.history[i]] = self.lamb * self.et[t].get(self.history[i], 0.0)

    # Assign the next state and action to the current state and action
    def stepForward(self):
        self.state = self.nextState
        self.action = self.nextAction
```

Here's what I've been using as a simulation.

```
import random
from qlearn.qlearn import QLearn, AutoVivification

# This simulates the process by which sales are realized and applies the Q-Learning algorithm to it
# Each series of episodes is repeated 1000 times in order to find the average revenue realized across all episodes

def main():
    # Define periods and episodes, instantiate the agent
    periods = 10
    episodes = 200
    agent = QLearn()
    revHistory = []
    firstSold = getSold(1,agent.action,agent.state)
    for k in range(1,episodes+1,1):
        revenue = 0
        # Process for first episode
        if k == 1:
            for t in range(1,periods+1,1):
                # Process for first period and episode
                if t == 1:
                    revenue = revenue + firstPeriodandEpisode(agent, firstSold)
                # Process for last period
                elif t == periods:
                    revenue = revenue + lastPeriod(agent, k, t)
                # Process for all other periods
                else:
                    revenue = revenue + update(agent, k, t)
        else:
            for t in range(1,periods+1,1):
                # Process for first period
                if t == 1:
                    revenue = revenue + firstPeriod(agent, k, t)
                # Process for last period
                elif t == periods:
                    revenue = revenue + lastPeriod(agent, k, t)
                # Process for all other periods
                else:
                    revenue = revenue + update(agent, k, t)
        # Updates number of visits to each state-action pair at the end each episode
        for i in range(1,periods+1,1):
            agent.visits[agent.history[i]] = agent.visits.get(agent.history[i],0) + 1
        revHistory.append(revenue)
    # Returns the final revenue realized 
    return revHistory[-1]

def firstPeriodandEpisode(agent, sold):
    # Creates dictionaries for eligibility traces and Q values
    agent.et = AutoVivification()
    agent.q = AutoVivification()
    # Gets the next state based on number sold
    agent.nextState = agent.getNextState(sold)
    # Calculates the reward by multiplying the number sold by the price
    agent.reward = agent.getReward(sold)
    # Chooses the next action by finding the maximum Q value
    agent.nextAction, agent.explore = agent.chooseAction(k=1, t=1)
    # Calculates the temporal difference error for the action
    agent.tdError = agent.TDError(k=1,t=1)
    # Assigns the number 1 to the current eligibility trace for the current state and action
    agent.et[1][(agent.state,agent.action)] = 1
    # Updates all Q values
    agent.updateQs(k=1,t=1)
    # Updates all eligibility traces
    agent.updateETs(k=1,t=1)
    # Advances time one step
    agent.stepForward()
    return agent.reward

def update(agent, k, t):
    # Gets number sold based on the equation in getSold()
    periodSold = getSold(t, agent.action, agent.state)
    # Gets the next state based on number sold
    agent.nextState = agent.getNextState(periodSold)
    # Calculates the reward by multiplying the number sold by the price
    agent.reward = agent.getReward(periodSold)
    # Chooses the next action by finding the maximum Q value
    agent.nextAction, agent.explore = agent.chooseAction(k, t)
    # Calculates the temporal difference error for the action
    agent.tdError = agent.TDError(k,t)
    # Assigns the number 1 to the current eligibility trace for the current state and action
    agent.et[t][(agent.state,agent.action)] = 1
    # Updates all Q values
    agent.updateQs(k,t)
    # Updates all eligibility traces
    agent.updateETs(k,t)
    # Advances time one step
    agent.stepForward()
    return agent.reward

def lastPeriod(agent, k, t):
    # Gets number sold based on the equation in getSold()
    periodSold = getSold(t, agent.action, agent.state)
    # Gets the next state based on number sold
    agent.nextState = agent.getNextState(periodSold)
    # Calculates the reward by multiplying the number sold by the price
    agent.reward = agent.getReward(periodSold)
    # Chooses the next action by finding the maximum Q value
    agent.nextAction, agent.explore = agent.chooseAction(k, t)
    # Calculates the temporal difference error for the action
    agent.tdError = agent.TDError(k,t)
    # Assigns the number 1 to the current eligibility trace for the current state and action
    agent.et[t][(agent.state,agent.action)] = 1
    # Updates all Q values
    agent.updateQs(k,t)
    # Updates all eligibility traces
    agent.updateETs(k,t)
    # Gets the action for the beginning of the next episode and makes it the current state
    agent.action, agent.explore = agent.nextEpisodeAction(k)
    # Sets current state to the beginning state
    agent.state = 15
    return agent.reward

def firstPeriod(agent, k, t):
    # All eligibility traces to 0
    agent.et = AutoVivification()
    # Clear state-action history
    agent.history = {}
    # Gets number sold based on the equation in getSold()
    periodSold = getSold(t, agent.action, agent.state)
    # Gets the next state based on number sold
    agent.nextState = agent.getNextState(periodSold)
    # Calculates the reward by multiplying the number sold by the price
    agent.reward = agent.getReward(periodSold)
    # Chooses the next action by finding the maximum Q value
    agent.nextAction, agent.explore = agent.chooseAction(k, t)
    # Calculates the temporal difference error for the action
    agent.tdError = agent.TDError(k,t)
    # Assigns the number 1 to the current eligibility trace for the current state and action
    agent.et[t][(agent.state,agent.action)] = 1
    # Updates all Q values
    agent.updateQs(k,t)
    # Updates all eligibility traces
    agent.updateETs(k,t)
    # Advances time one step
    agent.stepForward()
    return agent.reward

# Gets the number sold base on the time period, the action, and the state   
def getSold(t, action, state):
    if state == 0:
        sold = 0
    else:
        # Equation that simulates the amount sold
        sold = .3 + .25*t - .014*action
        if sold < 0:
            sold = 0
    return int(round(sold,0))   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    simRev = []
    for i in range(1,1001,1):
        simRev.append(main())
    # Prints the average final revenue over all simulations
    print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, simRev) / float(len(simRev))
```

The value that it spits out at the end should be somewhere close to 150, because that is the maximum that it should be finding, but for some reason it gets stuck around 80 no matter what I try.

Comment: Hi @user3704120, I edited your code block for legibility. When I pasted the block into my IDE, it highlighted the following issues: `reward`, `nextAction`, `nextState`, `tdError` & `et` are not attributes of the class `QLearn`. Could you also show how these attributes are set?

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be really useful here. How do you call your code, what output do you get, and what output do you want? Can you figure out at which step your code diverges from expectations, and how? Asking people to read a paper and then perform psychic debugging is doomed to failure.

Comment: It might be easier to refer you to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160212/help-with-application-of-temporal-difference-learning). It has a link with an implementation. Essentially, after a number of episodes the pricing policy I'm attempting to find should begin to converge to the optimum one, but I'm finding that it is not.